# Visual Studio Code shows TypeScript Error on startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

When starting Visual Studio Code, I get the following Error:

*The Path c:*\node_modules\typescript\lib doesn't point to a valid tsserver install.  TypeScript language features will be disabled.*

I'm not using typescript.

How do I tell vscode I'm not using typescript.

vs code version 1.8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error implies that you have the setting `"typescript.tsdk"` set to that path. It may be in the workspace settings of the folder you open, in the file at `.vscode/settings.json`. Or it may be in your user settings (F1 > `Open user settings`). Remove it, and the error should stop appearing.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51378#issuecomment-398215095